# Using front camera with zxing plugin

Tags: android, camera, barcode, zxing

I've searched but I couldn'find a right answer.
I want to use front camera for barcode scanning in my application. Could I do this without integrating zxing code in my app. Now I'am usenig intents for scanning.

Thank you.

Comment: Please find answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177291/xamarin-ios-zxing-barcode-read-using-front-camera-issue/45854321#45854321
[using zxing plugin in xamarin applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177291/xamarin-ios-zxing-barcode-read-using-front-camera-issue/45854321#45854321)
Hope it will help