# Xamarin iOS ZXing Barcode read using front camera issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, zxing

I am trying to implement a barcode scanning app using Xamarin and ZXing. Unfortunately scanning is not working well with front camera on iPhone and iPad. Any suggestions or help appreciated

Comment: Set property of UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = true in MobileBarcodeScanningOptions class

Answer (score 0):

Your InitializeScanner method can do scanner initialization as below and invokes start scanning, in my case I wanted to support barcode and QR code both. You can remove scanning option QRCode if you do not want to support it.
The callback mentioned while initialization is getting called back when scanner recognizes the code and returns unique string.
**The scanner option has property UseFrontCameraIfAvailable**

```
 var mobileBarcodeScanningOptions= new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions(); 
        mobileBarcodeScanningOptions.UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = true;
        mobileBarcodeScanningOptions.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
        ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
        ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_93,
        ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
        ZXing.BarcodeFormat.PDF_417,
        ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        };
        mobileBarcodeScanningOptions.AutoRotate = false;
        mobileBarcodeScanningOptions.TryHarder = true;
        mobileBarcodeScanningOptions.TryInverted = false;
       var scanview = new ZXingScannerView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height)) { }
        scanview.AutoFocus();

        //code to add your scanview in your main view
        scanview.StartScanning(MyScanResultHandler, mobileBarcodeScanningOptions);


 //After scanning code, scanner callbacks below method

    private void MyScanResultHandler(Result obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            //obj.Text gives you value of code in string which you can use further in your application
        }          

    }
```